# AWS EC2 boots via scheduled Lambda, how to alert of errors?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

My EC2 instance boots daily for 5 minutes before shutting down.

On bootup, a NodeJS script is executed. Usually this script will complete long before the 5 minutes are up, but I'd like to be notified (SMS/email) whenever it doesn't.

What is the correct approach? I can try to send a notification within my NodeJS code after 5 minutes if execution wasn't finished, but Lambda could shut down the instance before this occurs.

I'm quite new to AWS so I apologize if this is rather basic, I haven't had luck on Google with this issue.

Comment: Why would lambda "shut down the instance before this occurs"?

Comment: It is part of the Lambda function to boot, wait 5 minutes, then shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if whatever Node script is doing when EC2 instance is up could be replicated with one or more lambda functions.

Think about serverless and microservices architecture. Theoretically any workflow which need servers could be achived via AWS Lambda functions and various triggers. In you case I can think of the following:

1. SES to send out email messages
2. API gateway to expose your Lambda function for trigger
3. Cloud watch events to trigger lambda function like a cronjob.

I would be surprise to learn if Serverless won't work here. Please do share the case so that I can brainstorm more and share a solution.

Comment: I don't think so, the Node script (using Puppeteer) emulates Chrome so it can login to a website and upload a file (no public API is available). 
Maybe the focus needs be on my Node script and ensuring it completes in a timely matter.

Comment: Interesting! How about having a timer attached to your node function and trigger Lambda function pushing message into SQS or SES, if time > 4min?